# Can't get the access token in facebook sdk 5 login using php?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I hosted my files in **heroku** hosting. Facebook login callback file throws both the exceptions.

*First exception*

> Response Exception: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't
>   included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all
>   domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your
>   app settings.

*Second Exception* after reloading

> SDK Exception: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required
>   param "state" missing from persistent data.

**fb-callback.php**

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";
    try {

        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo "Response Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    } catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "SDK Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }

    if (!$accessToken) {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }

    $oAuth2Client = $FB->getOAuth2Client();
    if (!$accessToken->isLongLived())
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

    $response = $FB->get("/me?fields=id,name,email", $accessToken);
    $userData = $response->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
?>
```

I tried removing the try catch block and just used the statement

```
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

This caused error 500

> This page isn’t working
>
> fanism.herokuapp.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP
>   ERROR 500

**config.php**(used in fb-callback.php)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";

    $FB = new \Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '952208124958752',
        'app_secret' => '9088c861803fda4dadbe950915ae14f2',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'
    ]);

    $helper = $FB->getRedirectLoginHelper();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

created **composer.json** file in the project folder with the following code

```
{
  "require" : {
    "facebook/graph-sdk" : "~5.0"
  }
}
```

run command in project folder(command prompt)

```
composer install
```

facebook sdk folder(***vendor***) download and from that vendor folder, take out the ***Facebook*** folder and paste it in project.(deleted the previous manually downloaded Facebook folder)

then I uploaded that files normally to Heroku. Finally solved.